# Where is Recyle Bin for deleted Managed Path-based site?

Tags: recycle-bin, site-deletion, managed-path

Prior administrator created sites based on directory structure

http://abc.sharepoint.com/site/quality
http://abc.sharepoint.com/departments/IT
http://abc.sharepoint.com/departments/HR

/site and /departments are Managed Paths (**directories** -- not site collections or subsites).

When a Subsite is delete, I know to look to the Site Collection for the Recycle Bin.  Where is the Recycle Bin for such Managed Path-based sites?

Comment: Do you have the access to central admin> from central admin > application management > Manage web application. click on the abc.sarepoint.com web applition and from ribbon...Click on managed path...what you are seeing here.....also run this command > get-spsite http://abc.sharepoint.com/departments/HR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After improving the question with Waqas's help, I was able to get a list of the deleted Managed Path sites with:

```
Get-SPDeletedSite -webapplication "http://sharepoint.abc.com"
```

To Restore such a Managed Path Site, you can use the following:

```
$deletedSite = Get-SPDeletedSite /departments/secure_abc
Restore-SPDeletedSite -Identity $deletedSite
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> /site and /departments are directories -- not subsites.

Those are Site Collections, not directories. The answer to your question depends on the version of your SharePoint: 2007, 2010, 2013, 2016 or SharePoint Online. For 2010-2016 you can restore a deleted Site Collection using PowerShell. You will need to be a SharePoint Server Administrator with access to the SharePoint servers.

Here are the instructions for SP 2010-2016: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748655.aspx